# Upgrading to Rails 2.3.10 Stack Too Deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade

I've been having the weirdest time trying to upgrade to Rails 2.3.10 from 2.3.5. As soon as I upgraded, I can no longer run any tests. When I try running rake test:units for example, I see it get everything ready and then as soon as 'Started' appears is just hangs there. After a long time it eventually fails and just says 'stack level too deep'. That's about as helpful as the error is. The site runs fine when I boot up a mongrel to test out the site. I've tried making a new 2.3.10 app with all of the same gems and plugins and the tests ran fine in that project.

So, I'm totally stuck right now. Anyone else have this trouble?

Edit ---

Here's the whole stack trace. Warning! It's long!

```
Calebs-iMac:missionmakr keeker1$ rake test:recent --trace
(in /Users/keeker1/Documents/missionmakr)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/annotate_models/tasks, vendor/plugins   /delayed_job/tasks, vendor/plugins/fetcher/tasks, vendor/plugins/foreigner/tasks, vendor/plugins  /paperclip/tasks, vendor/plugins/qunit_for_rails/tasks, vendor/plugins/rails-fuzzy-search/tasks,   vendor/plugins/sms-fu/tasks, vendor/plugins/xss_terminate/tasks, and vendor/plugins/yaml_db/tasks    are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /Users/keeker1/Documents/missionmakr/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)
** Invoke test:recent (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load
** Execute test:recent
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/ruby -I"lib:test" "/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby- 1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/admin/announcement_test.rb" 
DEPRECATION WARNING: require "actionmailer" is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 3. Use   require "action_mailer" instead. (called from /Users/keeker1/Documents/missionmakr/vendor/rails /actionmailer/lib/actionmailer.rb:2)
Loaded suite /Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
EE
Finished in 254.876779 seconds.

1) Error:
test_should_create_new_announcement(AnnouncementTest):
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
/lib/fk_fixture_patch.rb:10:in `disable_referential_integrity'
/lib/fk_fixture_patch.rb:7:in `disable_referential_integrity'

2) Error:
test_should_show_error_when_message_is_blank(AnnouncementTest):
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
/lib/fk_fixture_patch.rb:10:in `disable_referential_integrity'
/lib/fk_fixture_patch.rb:7:in `disable_referential_integrity'

2 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302...]
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:995:in `sh'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1010:in `call'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1010:in `sh'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1094:in `sh'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1029:in `ruby'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1094:in `ruby'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/testtask.rb:117:in `define'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1112:in `verbose'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/testtask.rb:102:in `define'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in  `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/keeker1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/rake:19
Calebs-iMac:missionmakr keeker1$
```

I've also tried removing my patch lib/fk_fixture_patch.rb and it still didn't work.

Here's the code for the test_should_show_error_when_message_is_blank method.

```
def test_should_show_error_when_message_is_blank
   a = Announcement.create(:message => "", :starts_at => 3.days.from_now, :ends_at => 10.days.from_now)
   assert !a.valid?
end
```

The fk_fixture_patch.rb file is something for our server so we can load fixtures for test data. We use foreign key constraints in our database. I tried commenting out this code but the tests still wouldn't run.

Comment: Step 1: Post stack trace. Could be a conflicting gem or plugin.

Comment: I don't what the problem is, but I do know that the points changes between 2.3.5, 2.3.8, 2.3.9, and 2.3.10 each changed a lot of code. I'd recommend upgrading incrementally one point change at a time, and making sure everything works / dealing with any warnings at each step. (Skip 2.3.6 and 2.3.7 because both had severe bugs and were quickly upgraded to 2.3.8).

Comment: Ok, I posted the full stack trace. Thanks

Comment: What is "/lib/fk_fixture_patch.rb:10:in `disable_referential_integrity'" doing?

Comment: Please post the code for: test_should_show_error_when_message_is_blank and also the Announcement.rb model.

Comment: I still don't understand what is going on. The site runs perfectly fine but I can't get any of my tests to run. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured out what was going on! :)

I had an infinite loop problem in one of my models using the acts_as_tree plugin. Here's the bad line of code in my Comments model:

```
named_scope :parents, :conditions => {:parent_id => 0}
```

I guess since I had a column in my table called parent_id, ActiveRecord was getting messed up that I had a named scope called :parents. I renamed my scope to :parents_only and everything was back to normal. It's weird that the old code worked fine in Rails 2.3.5.... oh well

Thanks everyone for your help!

Caleb

Comment: Thanks! I had the exact same problem upgrading from Rails 2.3.5 to 2.3.11, except I didn't get a "stack too deep" error. Instead, my app maxed out the memory crippling the performance of my entire system. Upon further investigation, it looks like this is a result of the table name prefix support on modules added in Rails 2.3.6: [v2.3.6 release notes](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/5/23/ruby-on-rails-2-3-6-released), [commit that triggered this error](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/03d5d0b5f50161d8ec1b2b627e483aad7100494a)